# Interminent Delays in C++ Tcp Communication in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a device which sends data every 20 milliseconds over TCP. I have an application which connects to this device, starts the socket communication. My Application listens on a seperate thread and reads the data as fast as data is ready, puts data aside, and some other thread processes it. Device is directly connected to the computer via ethernet cable.

I see a strange problem and I am trying to understand the reason why, Almost once in every minute, it takes approximately  50 milliseconds to receive a packet from the device. I do a blocking read which will try reading for a second, and will finish as fast as data is ready, normally it takes approximately 20 ms as I would expect, but like I said before there are times it takes 50 ms even though it is very rare(1 in 3000). What I noticed is the packets after late packet arrives immediately, so it makes me think that there's some delay on the network layer. I also examined the timestamps of the packets(which is given by the device), they are consistenly increasing by 20 ms's.

Is it normal to see delays like that when the device is directly connected to the computer, Since it is TCP there might be lots of effort under the hood(CRC checks, out of order packages, retransmissions, etc). I still want to find an alternative way to prevent this delay than accepting the fact that it might happen.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put simply, **this is not what TCP is designed to do!**  The minute you use the word "packet" TCP is the wrong choice, as TCP is not intended for packet-oriented clients.  It's actually somewhat surprising you are not seeing 200ms delays from the Nagle Algorithm.

Comment: what would be your protocol of choice in a real time data processing scenario? Unfortunately TCP's what my device supports, I am obliged to use it.

Comment: It may be the device wasn't designed for this usage, or was intended for it but poorly engineered.  You can try a packet sniffer to see what is really going on, at an extreme you could use raw sockets to write your own phony-TCP implementation which tries to trick the device into performing better.  Or you could see if it has a serial port which might give you a lower latency alternative channel.  Or you can complain to its creators, or hack it and replace the firmware.

Comment: You're welcome.  As for how a low latency packet interface should be done, normally UDP, optionally with any tuned reliability-at-cost-of-delay scheme you feel appropriate layered on top.  But first make sure that your problem is truly latency; delays of some data doesn't necessarily mean that the overall data rate will fall behind, and you seem to be doing the processing asynchronously, so do you actually need to care about when the data arrives?  If there are timestamps (of sampling?) *in* the data chunks perhaps you can just use those and ignore arrival time.

Comment: Is the device itself running Linux? Are you able to log into that and interact with the filesystem?

Comment: thanks chris, if I synchronize late packets properly, I shouldn't be bothered by this latency at all, I am listening from 10 different devices, right now this latency is creating issues. I will try to make my algorithm latency proof

Comment: @neil, AFAIK I can't log into the device,but let me look into that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably result of [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) which is turned on by default in TCP/IP socket.

Use `setsockopt()` to set the `TCP_NODELAY` flag on socket that sends data to turn it off.

Comment: will it help if I create the socket by using TCP_NODELAY on the receiver side, I have no control over how sender device sends tcp packets?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The sender socket defines such behaviour.

Comment: @erinc Did you get the delay resolved using the above solution? We have a real time GPS navigation system implemented over TCP and facing similar delay issues for number of devices. Your insights might be helpful.